# How can I mass cutout people from stock photos with arbitrary backgrounds?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, image-manipulation, batch, masks

I have pictures that are going to be used to advertise clothing for a kids clothes shop.
I have a quite a large amount of photos (266 ). 
They are all similar to this:

[image: #1]

My job is to cut the children out and make it transparent. I was in shock since I was expecting a green screen of some sort.

So now I'm stuck with these pictures and the only way I know how to do it with a background like that is to manually use the selection tool.

Is there any other way, so that I don't have to waste my next 3 days, plotting dots around these kids to make a selection?

I have Photoshop/GIMP.

Comment: Photoshop has a [background eraser tool](http://www.photoshoptutorials.ws/photoshop-tutorials/basics/quick-tip-erase-backgrounds-quickly-background-eraser-tool/) (it's under the regular eraser). Online examples make it look very easy, not sure if it will work in your situation.

Comment: This is a topic very likely to attract spam; I'm preemptively marking it protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really any magical secret other than to reshoot.  Generally this type of photo is taken with a white background where the lighting makes it so the background doesn't have to be removed as it blends with the white of the background.

Your best bet is likely going to be to use a tablet and the quick selection tool to get the outlines quickly.  At least with a mostly consistent color background the selection should go pretty quickly as the quick selection tool will have an easy time of things.

Comment: Quick Selection Tool I believe is what AJ is referring to. This will be your best bet. For some outfits and hair styles you'll need to then refine with Quick Mask

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is any way to do mass masking, especially with an inconsistent background.  I would suggest a masking tool like [Topaz Remask](https://www.topazlabs.com/remask).  It would make pretty quick work of masking for these types of photos.

I was able to to create a mask for the sample image in about 1 minute with Remask. If I was using a stylus, I probably could have saved a few more seconds.

[image]